# Open a mutex shared with a service

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, mutex

I have a service that creates a thread with a loop that should run until the mutex is signalled by another process. I have the following in my service code

```
        private readonly Mutex _applicationRunning = new Mutex(false, @"Global\HsteMaintenanceRunning");

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(x => StartRunningThread()).Start();
        }

        internal void StartRunningThread()
        {
            while (_applicationRunning.WaitOne(1000))
            {
                FileTidyUp.DeleteExpiredFile();    
                _applicationRunning.ReleaseMutex();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
```

Now I have a console application that should claim the mutex and force the while loop to be exited

```
        var applicationRunning = Mutex.OpenExisting(@"Global\HsteMaintenanceRunning");
        if (applicationRunning.WaitOne(15000))
        {
            Console.Write("Stopping");
            applicationRunning.ReleaseMutex();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
```

When the console application tries to open the mutex I get the error  "The wait completed due to an abandoned mutex." Whats wrong here?

Comment: An abandoned mutex implies that a thread was terminated before releasing its hold on the mutex.  That makes me wonder if your service's DeleteExpiredFile() method is throwing an exception and therefore preventing the mutex from being released properly.

Comment: At the minute the method does nothing other than return 0. Its just a placeholder where code may go once I have the mutex working. Sorry for the confussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use the Service's built-in stop signal rather than a mutex.  The mutex class is more appropriate for managing exclusive access to a shared resource, which is not what's going on here.  You could also use a system event but since services already have a built-in mechanism for signaling when they're stopping, why not use it?

Your service's code would look like this:

```
bool _stopping = false;
Thread _backgroundThread;
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _backgroundThread = new Thread(x => StartRunningThread());
    _backgroundThread.Start();
}
protected override void OnStop()
{
    _stopping = true;
    _backgroundThread.Join(); // wait for background thread to exit
}
internal void StartRunningThread()
{
    while (!stopping)
    {
        FileTidyUp.DeleteExpiredFile();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Then, your console application would need to use the framework's ServiceController class to send the shut down message to your service:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
...
using (var controller = new ServiceController("myservicename")) {
    controller.Stop();
    controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15.0));
}
```